# I can't get my buttons to index properly

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

I'm having some issues with form tabindexing. I have two submit buttons in my form, and the one I want to be indexed first isn't. This is currently what I have on my buttons:

```
$form['prev']['#attributes']['tabindex'] = '0' 
$form['next']['#attributes']['tabindex'] = '1'
```

On this live version it shows up in the attributes they show up on both buttons.

I'm using Drupal 7 and creating my own custom form module.

Comment: Can you confirm that the tab index attributes are showing up in the HTML source, but they are just not behaving as expected?  I think that's what you're saying, I just want to confirm.

Comment: Yes that's exactly what's happening.

Comment: Are there other forms on the page that might be conflicting with the tab indexes?  If so, you may want to try setting those indexes to higher sequencial numbers.

Comment: Nope. It's a multi-step form that has a previous and next button, nothing else

Answer (score 0):

```
$form['company'] = array(
    '#title' => t('Company'),
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#required' => TRUE,
    '#attributes' => array('tabindex' => '6'),
);
```

this is how you set your tab index programatically.